# How can I set my Logitech G402 extra buttons as unassigned?

Tags: mouse, logitech-mouse

I while back I got a new mouse, the Logitech G402. It has 5 extra buttons on the side that do various things (change mouse sensitivity, back/forward etc). I didn't like this set up so I downloaded the Logitech Gaming software so I could turn off the buttons I don't want to use.

There are all sorts of options, but is there a way to set the button so that it's unassigned, but in a way that allows me to assign on a program-by-program basis? (like bind it to something in a game)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this so that you don't need to exit the game to reconfigure all of the time is to set those buttons to keys that few games use. Then you can just use your game interface to assign action to those rarely used keys which are actually mouse keys. You should be able to use the Logitech software to do this.

Comment: Do most games differentiate the num-pad from the numbers at the top of the keyboard? I could just bind everything to my num-pad and then bind my mouse buttons to the num-pad as well.

Comment: I did that for awhile but that turns out to be unreliable. Some games know the difference and some do not. I had three buttons to map so I've used '/', '*', '-'. These are on the numpad but are not affected by the numlock key.

Comment: I will try this when I get a chance.